# How can I display JSON results in a structured way on my own webpage from the OxyLab Shopping API?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am using the OxyLabs eCommerce Scraper API to scrape Google Shopping for various car parts. I am building a web page so that users fill out a car repair form, get a part recommendation to fix the problem, and then are shown all the places selling that part across the internet.

i have the first two parts down, but its displaying all the places selling the part that's more difficult.

**Anyone know how to display the data?**

**I have my API call in a file I've titled app.py under `get_recommended_parts`:**

```
def get_recommended_parts(query):
    payload = {
        "source": "google_shopping_search",
        "domain": "com",
        "query": query,
        "pages": 5,
        "context": [
            {"key": "sort_by", "value": "p"},
            {"key": "min_price", "value": 20}
        ],
        "parse": True
    }

    response = requests.post(
        'https://realtime.oxylabs.io/v1/queries',
        auth=('*(my username)*', '*(my password)*'),
        json=payload,
    )

    results = response.json().get('results', [])
    return results

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def fix_it_form():
    ai_analysis = None
    recommended_parts = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        car_make = request.form['carMake']
        car_model = request.form['carModel']
        car_year = request.form['carYear']
        issue_type = request.form['issueType']
        issue_description = request.form['issueDescription']

        ai_analysis = analyze_issue_with_context(car_make, car_model, car_year, issue_type, issue_description)
        recommended_parts = get_recommended_parts(ai_analysis)  # Use the diagnosis as the query

    return render_template('fix_it_form.html', ai_analysis=ai_analysis, recommended_parts=recommended_parts)
```

**And then here's how I'm linking it in my HTML file:**

```
{% if recommended_parts %}
<div class="recommended-parts">
    <h2>Recommended Car Parts:</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for part in recommended_parts %}
            <li>
                <strong>Title:</strong> {{ part.get('title', 'N/A') }}<br>
                <strong>Price:</strong> {{ part.get('price_str', 'N/A') }}<br>
                <strong>Link:</strong> <a href="{{ part.get('url', '#') }}" target="_blank">{{ part.get('merchant', {}).get('name', 'N/A') }}</a><br>
                <strong>Image:</strong> <img src="{{ part.get('image', '#') }}" alt="Part Image"><br>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

**And below, is what the web page produces and also what the JSON item structure looks look:**

[image: Failed API call]

[image: JSON item structure]